# Which hell do people who interpolate scriptures go to?

Tags: scripture, interpolation, hell

There are many kinds of hell in Hinduism, but I have not seen any specific reference to hell for people who interpolate scriptures or propagate interpolated scriptures for political aims (like Arya Samajis).

Is there any such hell?